# Add values to a Select and sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several Select which depend on each other if I select a value in one of the other is removed, and the previous value is added to others, how I can add the previous value by JQuery to Select? and then sort it alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the sorting (shouldn't be too hard to figure out) but you can append an `<option>` element to a list like this:

```
$("#myselect").append(
    $("<option>").prop("selected", "selected").attr("value", "OptionValue").text("OptionText")
);
```

The first call to `prop()` is only if you need the element to be the selected one in the list, otherwise you can omit it.

Edit: I went ahead and worked out the sort part:

```
var elems = [];
$("#sortable > option").each(function () {
    elems.push({ key: $(this).val(), value: $(this).text() });
});

elems.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
    if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
    return 0;
});

$("#sortable").empty();
$.each(elems, function (idx, item) {
    $("#sortable").append(
        $("<option>").attr("value", item.key).text(item.value)
    );
});
```

Comment: `selected` should be `prop()` not `attr()`. Right ? Btw +1 for a nice code

Comment: It should? Seems to work fine with `attr`. Is there something about that attribute that is better handled with `prop`?

Comment: It was a question cum suggestion. I wasnt sure, so I added `Right ?`.
[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) should replace `attr()` when dealing with `properties`

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to work with either, but if jQuery says that should be done that way then who am I to question :) I updated the first sample.

Comment: I appreciate your attitude. Just wanted to share the new thing I read on jQuery docs :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the code for adding values is available, here is the code for sorting values in select

```
function sortOptions()
{
    var arr = [];
    $("#myselect option").each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).html());
    });
    $('#myselect').empty();
    arr.sort();
    var html='';
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        html+='<option>' + arr[i] + '</option>'
    }
    $('#myselect').html(html);
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your example code, one question, JQuery has the option of Sortable Interaction, maybe i could use?

Comment: If you are talking about the [jQuery UI Sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) I don't think it would solve your above mentioned problem. "The jQuery UI Sortable plugin makes selected elements sortable by dragging with the mouse." as posted on their page

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't really "order" the DOM elements.

The best approach for this is propably to read out all the elements of the select to which an element should be added into an array, add the new values to the array and then sort it. The DOM elements should be removed during this process of course. Afterwards you add the newly ordered elements to the DOM again in the desired order.